# reinterpret_cast, read-only access, trivially copyable types, what can go wrong?

Tags: c++

It is well known that accessing `reinterpret_cast<pointer/reference>(obj)`'s result is undefined behavior (except in a few cases).

Now, suppose, that you only do read-only access to `obj` during the lifetime of the reinterpret_cast'd variable:

```
TypeA *a = ...;
{
    const TypeB *b = reinterpret_cast<const TypeB*>(a);
    // b's lifetime is this scope

    // I know, that accessing the object pointed by 'b' is UB
    // but what can go wrong in practice in this scope,
    // if the code uses 'a' and 'b' only in a read-only manner,
    // for example:
    cout << a->something;
    cout << b->otherSomething;
}
```

(`TypeA` and `TypeB` are trivially copyable and unrelated; and suppose that we have no aligment issues here)

My main question: would we lose any optimization potential, if the standard allowed this?

I mean, that instead of the current principle, this would be only UB, if the reachable memory through `b` would be actually modified during the lifetime of `b` (by any means).

Is it a sensible idea?

---

Examples, where this idea could be useful:

- there's a `char8_t` [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r4.html), which would put a new character type into the standard, which is not allowed to alias. Now suppose, that a codebase changes to this type. And there is a legacy library, which is used by this codebase, which keeps using `char` for storing utf-8. Now, if we want to avoid UB, we need to *copy* between `char` and `char8_t`. But these are actually the same in memory, so a `reinterpret_cast` should do the job.
- a simple `reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t&>(some_float)` could be well-defined with this idea. There would be no need for `bit_cast`.

Comment: With `const TypeB *b = reinterpret_cast<const TypeB*>(a)` there's no copying of objects. What's being copied is the *pointer* only.

Comment: As for your problem, it really depends on `TypeA` and `TypeB` if the behavior is defined or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: yes, that's the point. Currently, the standard disallows this (I mean, reinterpret_cast), so we need to apply a copy instead, to be standard conformant. If this was allowed, then we don't need the copy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: TypeA and TypeB are trivially copyable, but otherwise unrelated. So this is UB in current standard. But the question is not about this.

Comment: So what is the question? If it were allowed you could reinterpret_cast, but it is not allowed in general, so the general solution is a copy?!?! Sorry, I am lost

Comment: Why would the standard disallow casting between (related) ***pointer*** types (which is what your code does)? Can you please elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: they are unrelated, that's what I written in my comment previously.

Comment: i am quite lost on your "bachground" if two types are "actually the same", then why would you need/use a `reinterpret_cast` between them?

Comment: @user463035818: they are different types. But they interpret the memory in the same way.

Comment: Are you talking about this [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r1.html)?

Comment: @Pi: yes, here's a newer version: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r4.html

Comment: And the question is now, what happend if they added a new char-type that may NOT alias anymore?

Comment: @Pi: No. The `char8_t` case is just an example, where my idea could be useful.

Comment: Now I get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing restriction ease compilation and optimization. Suppose you have this code:

```
TypeA *a = ...;
{
    const TypeB *b = reinterpret_cast<const TypeB*>(a);
    cout << a->something;
    cout << b->otherSomething;
}
a->modifier();
```

The compiler need to know that `*b` is an alias for `*a` so that it does not reorder to this:

```
TypeA *a = ...;
const TypeB *b = reinterpret_cast<const TypeB*>(a);
cout << a->something;
a->modifier();
cout << b->otherSomething;
```

In this case the analysis would be easy, but imagine one declares a `void f(TypeA* a, const TypeB* b)`. Inside the body of `f`, previous reordering would be a disaster. Shall the compiler refuse to call any function with `a` and `b` as argument? Or shall we inform the compiler that first parameter of `f` may be aliased: `void f(TypeA* __unrestricted a, const TypeB* __unrestricted b)`?

I am sure this would be the beginning of endless discussion. Moreover it is not in the fashion trend (see Rust).

Comment: Good point. I'm thinking about how to avoid this, but I've no good idea yet, so no endless discussion (yet) :)

Comment: @geza Do you know Rust [reference borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html)? Maybe a "borrowing" analysis could be performed in a similar way, to allow such code, but I fill this would lead to a completely different language.

Comment: nope. I've always wanted to check out Rust, now I will.